# Automorphism Proof With a Product of Cyclic Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I prove that $Aut(\Bbb Z/35)\cong C_4 \times C_6$, where $C_n$ is the multiplicative version of the cyclic group of order $n$, i.e. $C_n \cong \Bbb Z/n$? Thanks!

Comment: Note that $Aut(\Bbb Z_{35})\cong\Bbb Z_{35}^*$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

As mentioned by @hellotinfish, an automorphism of $\mathbf Z/35\mathbf Z$ maps its generator $1\bmod35$ onto another generator, i.e. onto a unit of $\mathbf Z/35\mathbf Z$.

On the other hand you can use the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
$$\mathbf Z/35\mathbf Z\simeq \mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z,\quad\text{whence }\enspace(\mathbf Z/35\mathbf Z)^\times\simeq (\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)^\times\times (\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z)^\times. $$

Comment: Thanks, I see it now!